# Cross connection query (Oracle, MS Access) with Toad data point

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, toad

Using Toad Data Point, I want to query an *Oracle* database and export my resultset into a new *MS Access* Table via the `INTO`-Keyword.

A simple query to that database would look like this, with `hr.` in front of the actual table name.

```
select
    *
from
    hr.zy00
```

Here is a simplified version of what I would do **if** it was two *MS Access* databases (tested it in toad, worked great):

```
select
    *
into
    new_table in 'c:\destination.accdb'
from
    hr.zy00 in 'c:\source.accdb'
```

Instead, i want to get data `INTO` access `FROM` oracle using similar SQL.

Both the connections are set up and working. Here is a screen of my oracle connection profile.

[image: oracle profile]

I've read in on *cross connection queries* in Toad, but my version is lacking the documented menu items. [This](http://dev.toadfordataanalyst.com/webhelp/Content/Query_Builder/Create_CrossConnection_Queries.htm) suggests there is a way of doing this purely in SQL. However, I fail to translate what I know into the example.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**Additional info:**

- Data Point Version 3.7.0.973 base edition
- MS Access 2010
- while this can be done with the Export-Wizard, I want to have this in clean SQL for a variety of reasons
- **Edit:** access to the *Oracle* db is restricted to certain tools by corporate it, so i can't query from *Access* directly.

Comment: Access supports the `IN` syntax with ODBC data sources just fine. No need to use toad nor the export wizards, you can just do this only using SQL in Access if you wish.

Comment: @ErikA thanks for your reply. access to the db is restricted by corporate it to certain tools, which means that I have to use toad. Edited my post accordingly.

Comment: have you `tested` ODBC connection in MS ACCESS to connect to Oracle Db? did you get any specific error message?

Comment: i get a timeout message, which is basically the same that i get when using SAS Enterprise Guide. As I said, the IT department informed me that access is restricted, and that TOAD is currently the only application allowed.